# SVG ball causes extra space in webkit browsers

Tags: html, css, svg

I am new to svg and experimenting to create some balls using svg .

```
<style>
.container{
    width:420px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.div1 {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
}
.div2 {
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
    width:200px;
}
</style>


<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">
        This is description, image or anything
    </div>

    <div class="div2">    
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="15" fill="#df6c4f" />
            <circle cx="60" cy="30" r="15" fill="#ecd06f" />
            <circle cx="90" cy="30" r="15" fill="#409f89" />
            <circle cx="120" cy="30" r="15" fill="#1a99aa" />
        </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="div1">
        This is description, image or anything
    </div>

    <div class="div2">    
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="15" fill="#df6c4f" />
            <circle cx="60" cy="30" r="15" fill="#ecd06f" />
            <circle cx="90" cy="30" r="15" fill="#409f89" />
            <circle cx="120" cy="30" r="15" fill="#1a99aa" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

But in webkit browsers, I can see a extra space between `div1` and `div2` . How can I remove it ?
[TEST](http://jsfiddle.net/4rpy5/)

[image: Mozilla]

[image: Chrome]

Comment: What extra space is the problem? Remove the width and the left margin: http://jsfiddle.net/4rpy5/1/

Comment: Please see the images. In chrome you can see the margin between `div1` and `div2` is much higher than in mozilla

Comment: They look exactly the same to me. It could be that the browsers are rendering fonts differently so it seems as the margin is different, but the actual divs are the same. Try putting borders on them and you'll see.

Comment: The height of the balls `div2` is much bigger in chrome. Giving a height to the `div2` is making them equal though

Answer (score 2):

Remove the width of div1 and the left margin of div2 and there will be no space: http://jsfiddle.net/4rpy5/1/

If you want the balls to touch the edge of div1, change their offsets to match the radius: http://jsfiddle.net/4rpy5/2/

```
<circle cx="15" cy="15" r="15" fill="#df6c4f" />
```